# ExtJS - make ComboBox show all items on focus

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to make a ComboBox search field, in which the store of items is not list of values to search, Each item of the list is a link (should invoke some saved query).

But I should be possible to insert free text to the field.

I want it to open the list on focus (when I click on the field)

I've tried this: `editable: false` but it prevent me from insert text.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `listeners: {focus: function(field) {field.expand()} }`

Comment: Great! Thank you! :)